# Solve the diophantine equation $3\,{a}^{3}b-13\,{b}^{3}-26\,a-24\,b=0.$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Solve the diophantine equation  $3\,{a}^{3}b-13\,{b}^{3}-26\,a-24\,b=0.$
I have found two obvious solutions $a=b=0$ and $a=b=5.$ Are there another solutions?

Comment: Just a quick observation before I leave to catch the train ... $3b(a^3-2^3)=13(b^3+2a)$ and $b \ne 13$ so $b \mid 2a$

Comment: why $b \neq 0 \mod 13? $

Comment: because if it was, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3(x%5E3-8)%3D13%5E3+%2B+2x

Comment: then  what about $b=26, 39,\ldots ? $

Comment: Yes, that observation didn't work.

Comment: However, case 1: $a=b$ leads to https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3*x%5E4-13*x%5E3-26*x-24*x%3D0, i.e. $0, 5$ as the only solutions for this case. I will abuse Wolfram Alpha, but essentially, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem is all we need.

Comment: Case 2: $\gcd(a,b)=1$ leads to $b \cdot Q = 26 \cdot a$ which means $b=1$, $b=2$, $b=13$ or $b=26$ and again, none of the resulting polynomials in $a$ have integer solutions. E.g. $b=1$ yields $3a^3-26a-37=0$ and according to rational root theorem an integer root of this polynomial should divide 37, which is a prime and $a=1$ or $a=-1$ are not solutions.

Comment: The remaining case is $\gcd(a,b)=k>1$ ... which, so far, looks tricky.

Comment: Some context could be helpful. Where did this equation come from?

Answer (score 6):

Let us try to find a non-zero solutions of Diophantine equation.

Let
$$c=\gcd(a,b),\quad a=cx,\quad b=cy,$$
then
$$x(3c^3x^2y-26)=y(13c^2y^2+24),$$
$$y\,|\,(3c^3x^2y-26),\quad y\,|\, 26,$$
$$3c^3x^3-\dfrac{26}yx = 13c^2y^2 + 24,\quad y\in\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm13,\pm26\}.$$
Taking in account that for any values of $y$ the implicit function $x(c)$ is the asymptote on the coordinate axes and that negative values of $c$ correspond to the opposite values $y,$ we are at each value of $ y $ can get all integer solutions of this equation $(1)$.

All values $(x,y),$ which gives $c\gtrsim 5,$ obtained with using of Mathcad package, are the next:

[image]

With the [graphic1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%203c%5E3x%5E3-26x%3D13c%5E2%2B24,%20(c%5E2-1)(x%5E2-1)(x%5E2-4)%3D0) for $y=\pm1,$ [graphic2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%203c%5E3x%5E3-13x%3D52c%5E2%2B24,%20(c%5E2-1)(x%5E2-1)%3D0) for $y=\pm2,$ [graphic3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2013c%5E3x%5E3-x%3D2197c%5E2-24,%20(c%5E2-1)(c%5E2-4)(c%5E2-9)(c%5E2-16)(c%5E2-25)%3D0,%20%7Cx%7C%3C5) for $y=\pm13$ and [graphic4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2013c%5E3x%5E3-x%3D8788c%5E2-24,%20(c%5E2-1)(c%5E2-4)(c%5E2-9)(c%5E2-16)(c%5E2-25)%3D0) for $y=\pm26$ we have all possible integer roots for $x,y,c$.

Among them only $c(1,1) = 5$ is integer. Substituting of $a=b=5$ to the original equation shows that this is the right solution.

So
$$\boxed{(a=0,b=0) \vee (a=5,b=5)}$$ 
are the all integer solutions of the given Diofantine equation.

**Note**

Of course, in each of these cases, we can show the presence or absence of integer roots using the Rational Root Theorem. However, in this case that looks like a very technical and overload the main logic of proof.

Comment: One single case is missing, for $a=b$

Comment: @rtybase what about x=y=1, c=a?

Comment: then $26 \vdots y$ part is in trouble ;)

Comment: @rtybase Somewhere, number 1 was divider for all ... I missed something?;)

Comment: The entire section $$x(3c^3x^2y-26)=y(13c^2y^2+24),$$
$$(3c^3x^2y-26)\ \vdots\ y,\quad 26\ \vdots\ y,$$
doesn't make sense for $x=y=1$, $c=a$. It's a simple corner case to deal with.

Comment: @rtybase $y=1$ is one of cases when $26\ \vdots\ y$, this is the sense

Comment: @rtybase, the notation is unconventional.  By $26\,\vdots\,y$, he actually means $y\mid 26$.

Comment: I know, but ... $a=b$ leads to $$3a^3-13a^2-50=0$$ which is not equivalent to $$3c^3x^3-26x = 13c^2 + 24$$
unless $x=1$ ... it's a little subtle annoying thing that is really easy to deal with :) ... I don't know how easier to explain it

Comment: @rtybase, but he is right that $x=y=1$ covers your case $a=b$ (I don't think plotting should be considered to be a solution, but that's more of a personal view).

Comment: @Wiley fixed notation, thank you.

Comment: Well, just imagine how easy it is to apply Rational Root Theorem to $3a^3-13a^2-50=0$. It's one case done without plotting.

Comment: @rtybase It takes a lot of things to turn my thoughts into a rigorous proof (eg, investigate the asymptotic behavior of the function $c(x)$). But my task is to indicate a constructive approach.

Comment: @rtybase The value is known, the test is successful.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov ok, ok ... up-voted ;)